# How does Gradle find org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-html-jvm:0.7.2?

Tags: gradle, kotlin-dokka, dokka

I have been trying for hours to get dokka to work under gradle, but I cannot find any combination of versions that is able to resolve dependencies. For example

```
ekolotyluk@MacBook-Pro microservices % ./gradlew dokkaHtml
> Task :dokkaHtml FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':dokkaHtml'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':dokkaHtmlPlugin'.
   > Could not find org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-html-jvm:0.7.2.
     Required by:
         project : > org.jetbrains.dokka:dokka-base:1.4.10.2
```

In my build.gradle I have

```
dokka_version = "1.4.10.2"
. . .
repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/dokka/" }
    maven { url "https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlinx" }
}

plugins {
    id "org.jetbrains.dokka" version "$dokka_version"
}
```

According to https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jetbrains.kotlinx/kotlinx-html-jvm/0.7.2 it should be in https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlinx/ but according to Gradle, it cannot be found.

While I have been using Maven for over a decade, I am fairly new to Gradle. Any help or tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I got it working after updating my Android project's top-level `build.gradle` to include this repo:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        //https://github.com/kotlin/kotlinx.html/wiki/Getting-started
        maven { url "https://maven.pkg.jetbrains.space/public/p/kotlinx-html/maven" }
    }
}
```